# Error connecting py2neo

Tags: python, python-2.7, neo4j, py2neo

I'm trying to connect my neo4J DB with Python using py2neo.

I'm following the example extracted from py2neo 2 API but there's no way to get it work.

My code:

```
from py2neo import Graph
graph = Graph("http://neo4j:1234@localhost:7474/C:/Users/htilmatine/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb")
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\TFG\python\ejm.py", line 1, in <module>
    from py2neo import Graph
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2neo-2.0a0-py2.7.egg\py2neo\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from py2neo.batch import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2neo-2.0a0-py2.7.egg\py2neo\batch\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from py2neo.batch.core import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2neo-2.0a0-py2.7.egg\py2neo\batch\core.py", line 24, in <module>
    from py2neo.core import NodePointer, Service
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2neo-2.0a0-py2.7.egg\py2neo\core.py", line 50, in <module>
    from py2neo.error.client import BindError, JoinError
ImportError: No module named error.client
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connection docs are [here](http://py2neo.org/2.0/essentials.html#the-graph).

If you're just using a default install and default graph data directory, you should be able to connect with:

```
graph = Graph("http://neo4j:1234@localhost:7474/db/data")
```

or

```
from py2neo import ServiceRoot
graph = ServiceRoot("http://neo4j:1234@localhost:7474").graph
```

If you're not using the default data directory then

- it needs to be a subdirectory of `/neo4j/data`
- you need to provide a relative path to it from the neo4j directory in your uri like:

  `graph = Graph("http://neo4j:1234@localhost:7474/db/data/my_graph_dir")`

EDIT: fixed the first Graph url, and added how to connect with `ServiceRoot`

Comment: I've just reinstalled Neo4j 2.2.9 and the default directory is= C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community

Tried with graph = Graph("http://neo4j:neo4j@localhost:7474") and it still gives me the same error..

Comment: Well, tried with ServiceRoot too and still gives me the same error.

graph = ServiceRoot("http://neo4j:1234@localhost:7474/db/data/C:/Users/htilmatine/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb").graph

Comment: I think if you're using `graph = Graph()` to connect you have to specify it with `/db/data` like: `Graph("neo4j:neo4j@localhost:7474/db/data")`

Comment: I don't think `ServiceRoot` expects the full directory, just try:  `graph = ServiceRoot("neo4j:1234@localhost:7474")`.   Is Neo4j running? Can you open it in a browser when you go to `http://localhost:7474` ?

Comment: What path do you refer after /db/data? I'm using the same path that indicates neo4j program when you launch it. I'm refering to the field "Database Location".

Comment: Ok, I executed `from py2neo import ServiceRoot` through the Python command line instead of the IDLE and it gives me the same error. So the problem is not with the graph directory.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I'm concerned about seeing `py2neo-2.0a0` in your path name. I'd strongly recommend using a more up-to-date version of py2neo, specifically not an alpha release.